# Escaping special characters in AD group name

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I am trying to add a group to Azure SQL database. I am logged in active directory admin.

```
CREATE USER [$G(AUS)-DataengineeringTeam] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
GO
```

Result

> '$G(AUS)-DataengineeringTeam' is not a valid login or you do not have permission.

Something like below works fine

```
CREATE USER [azure-sandbox-reader] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
```

GO

The group exists in Azure AD.

[image: Ad group image]

Comment: Azure AD user/group name doesn't support special characters, include '$'.

Comment: @LeonYue Group is there is azure ad.

Comment: A lot of AzAD properties don't allow `(` and `)` characters in them, including targetAddresses and userPrincipalNames. Have you tried using the result of `(Get-AzureADGroup -Filter "DisplayName eq '$G(AUS)-DataengineeringTeam'").ObjectId` instead?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Thanks for that, but original question is more regarding using the group name with $ and "( )" in create user statement in tsql.

Comment: Hey @Sid,
DId the below answer solve your query?

Comment: @Nandan Yes I am going to get new groups created without special characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are limitations on the characters you can use in the name of an AD Group or user.

Characters allowed

A – Z

a - z

0 – 9

' . - _ ! # ^ ~

You will be able to create the group from Azure portal, but the limitations apply while using the names from PowerShell, T-SQL or CLI.
If you need to use the AD objects programmatically, please use the allowed characters suggested above.

In case if you want to grant the above group access, then you need to follow  any below 2 steps:

1. Create another group and add the $ grp in the newly created grp.
   And give access to the newly created grp in database
2. make the DL AD admin of server as you would be able to browse the group: but this is a security risk as you would be giving Admin rights